# A PHP code snippet works when in Wordpress Elementor editor but not in the page when displayed in browser

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor, wordpress-shortcode

Using Code Snippet plugin and Elementor, I am trying to display a custom type post (Events from "The Events Calendar" plugin).

The following code works well with another custom post type I created myself.

```
add_shortcode('events_grid', 'events_grid');

function events_grid($atts)
{

  // Attributes
  extract(
    shortcode_atts(
      array(
        'limit' => '-1',
        'columns' => '3',
        'status' => 'publish',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'include' => '',
        'exclude' => '',
        'paged' => ''
      ),
      $atts
    )
  );

  echo '<h1>Snippet is working</h1>';
  // Global vars
  global $post;
  $post_type = "tribe_events";
  $html = "";

  $query_args = array(
    'post_type' => $post_type,
  );

  $my_query = new WP_Query($query_args);
      echo "<h2>my_query->have_posts():</h2>";
      echo '<pre>';
         var_dump($my_query->have_posts());
      echo '</pre>';
    
    
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    
  if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
            
      echo '<p>' . $post->ID . '</p>';

    endwhile;
  endif;
    
  wp_reset_query();

  return $html;
}
```

That's what I see in Elementor:

[image: What I see in Elementor]

Basically, it looks like that in Elementor, my query has been done twice. The first one doesn't return any posts. The second one instead gets post correctly.

But that's what I see when opening page in browser:

[image: What I see in page]

When on page, only the first query runs and gets no posts.

But why are there multiple queries? And why only Elementor runs both? I really can't get it.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that, with the free version of The Events Calendar, Elementor renders both past and future events (the first call you see is for future events only, the second one for both future and past events), while, when in the page in browser, only future events are rendered.

I tested it when I hadn't any future event, that's why my events' array was empty.